# "Duplicate key value violates unique constraint". Используется "get_or_create" с "ManyToMany"

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Имеются циклы, которые раскидывают информацию по БД. Видно из “принт-логов” ниже.
При первом проходе все создается нормально. При втором проходе создается второй инстанс (тот же фильм, только жанр изменен), но данный код

```
show_movie.showsMovie_originCountry.get_or_create(placeCountry_name=country)
```

, который идет после создания инстанса и который должен связать Фильм со Страной через many2many, выдает ошибку

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "place_countries_placeCountry_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key ("placeCountry_name")=(Польша) already exists.
```

Если перед запуском кода в базе имеется запись "Польша", то первый проход цикла проверяет "Польшу" и ошибок не выдает.

Чтобы разобраться, в чем причина, принтами сделал подобие логов:

```
# Первый проход\инстанс
DEBUG -> show_movie: id: 42 ---->>>> Добрый день, я люблю тебя! ---->>>> Мелодрама
DEBUG -> country: Польша
DEBUG -> films_cast: Алексей Коморовский, Барбара Курдей, Павел Домагала
DEBUG -> actor_position: (<ShowPersonsInShows: Актер>, False)
DEBUG -> actor_position: (<ShowPersonsInShows: Актер>, False)
DEBUG -> actor_position: (<ShowPersonsInShows: Актер>, False)
DEBUG -> films_producer: Рышард Заторский
DEBUG -> producer_position: (<ShowPersonsInShows: Режиссер>, False)
DEBUG -> films_scenarist: Рышард Заторский
DEBUG -> scenarist_position: (<ShowPersonsInShows: Сценарист>, False)
# Второй проход\инстанс
DEBUG -> show_movie: id: 43 ---->>>> Добрый день, я люблю тебя! ---->>>> Комедия
DEBUG -> country: Польша
Traceback (most recent call last):
####
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "place_countries_placeCountry_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key ("placeCountry_name")=(Польша) already exists.
```

Кусок models.py #1:

```
class Shows(models.Model):
    show_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    show_poster = models.ImageField('Poster')
    show_screen = models.ImageField('Screens')
    show_genre = models.CharField('Genre', max_length=20, blank=True)
    # show_length = models.IntegerField('Length', null=True)
    show_length = models.TimeField('Time', null=True)
    show_ageLimit = models.IntegerField('Age limit', null=True)
    show_description = models.TextField('Description', blank=True)
    show_youtubeUrl = models.URLField('Youtube', max_length=255, blank=True)

    show_person = models.ManyToManyField(ShowPersons,
                                         through='ShowPersonsInShows',
                                         related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related',
                                         verbose_name="People in movie")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'shows'
        verbose_name = 'Show'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Shows'
        ordering = ['show_name']

class ShowsMovies(Shows):
    showsMovie_originalName = models.CharField('Original name', max_length=100, blank=True)
    showsMovie_budget = models.IntegerField('Budget', null=True)
    showsMovie_productionYear = models.IntegerField('Production year', null=True)
    showsMovie_officialSite = models.URLField('Official site', max_length=255, blank=True)

    showsMovie_originCountry = models.ManyToManyField('app_places.PlaceCountries',
                                                      verbose_name='Origin country',
                                                      db_table='m2m_shows_movies_to_place_countries')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'shows_movies'
        verbose_name = 'Show Type - Movie'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Show Type - Movie'
```

Кусок models.py #2:

```
class PlaceCountries(models.Model):
    placeCountry_name = models.CharField("Country's Name", max_length=60, unique=True)
    placeCountry_short_name = models.CharField("Country's Short name", max_length=5, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'place_countries'
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'
        ordering = ['placeCountry_name']
```

Код:

```
for genre in films_genre.title().split(', '):
    show_movie, created = ShowsMovies.objects.get_or_create(
        show_name=film,
        show_genre=genre,
        show_length=films_length,
        show_ageLimit=films_age,
        show_description=films_description,
        show_youtubeUrl=films_youtube_url,

        showsMovie_originalName=films_original_name,
        showsMovie_productionYear=films_year,
    )

    print('DEBUG -> show_movie:', 'id:', show_movie.id, '---->>>>', show_movie.show_name, '---->>>>', show_movie.show_genre)

    for country in films_country.split(', '):
        print('DEBUG -> country:', country)
        # Место возникновения ошибки
        show_movie.showsMovie_originCountry.get_or_create(placeCountry_name=country)

    if films_cast != ' ':
        print('DEBUG -> films_cast:', films_cast)

        for actor in films_cast.split(', '):  # и таких еще 2 цилка, только для продюсера и сценариста

        get_showPersonsInShow_person, created = ShowPersons.objects.get_or_create(showPerson_fullname=actor)
        get_showPersonsInShow_show, created = Shows.objects.get_or_create(show_name=film, show_genre=genre)

        actor_position = ShowPersonsInShows.objects.get_or_create(
            showPersonsInShow_person=get_showPersonsInShow_person,
            showPersonsInShow_show=get_showPersonsInShow_show,
            showPersonsInShow_position='Актер'
        )

        print('DEBUG -> actor_position:', actor_position)
```

Полный трейс:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.films_list()
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser.py", line 91, in films_list
    self.detailed_films_info(films_dict)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/idemvdvoem.com/src/shared/parser.py", line 285, in detailed_films_info
    show_movie.showsMovie_originCountry.get_or_create(placeCountry_name=country)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1029, in get_or_create
    obj, created = super(ManyRelatedManager, self.db_manager(db)).get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 407, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in _create_object_from_params
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 659, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 439, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 348, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 734, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 762, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 846, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 885, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 974, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/antonio/projects/idemvdvoem.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "place_countries_placeCountry_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key ("placeCountry_name")=(Польша) already exists.
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что тут могло быть так? get_or_create ожидает наличие только одного результата, у вас по запросу

```
show_movie.showsMovie_originCountry.get_or_create(placeCountry_name=country)
```

более одного резульата

Уточните, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, в коде куча логических ошибок: скажем переменная films_country судя по всему содержит список стран, участвующих в создании фильма, было бы логичнее назвать её film_countries а то мозг взрывается. Префиксы тоже не нужно лепить направо и налево, это unpythonic и поддерживать такой код после вас будет очень тяжело, да и вам тоже будет тяжело, именно из за плохой читаемости и всплывают подобные ошибки. атрибут "showsMovie_originCountry" логичнее именовать "countries" т.к. связь у нас m2m то есть стран для фильма может быть много. А модель "PlaceCountries" должна называться Country.

Непонятно, как будут создаваться страны, ведь placeCountry_short_name нигде не указывается, нужно либо ставить в него Blank=True, либо убирать его вообще, либо генерировать на лету в методе save модели, либо вообще разумнее страны загрузить заранее, благо их не так уж и много существует, и найти этот список - не проблема

По сути вопроса: если вы хотите связать фильм со списком стран, нужно
написать в моделе ShowMovie следующий метод-менеджер:

```
def get_country_or_create(self, country_name=None):
    try:
        country = Country.objects.get(name=country_name)
    except:
        country = Country.objects.create(name=country_name)

    self.showsMovie_originCountry.add(country)
    return self
```

и в том месте, где находится ваш код, написать

```
for country_name in films_country.split(', '):
    show_movie.get_country_or_create(country_name=country_name)
```

Вообще идея создания копии фильма для каждого жанра выглядит сомнительной, вам просто нужно создать таблицу жанр и сделать связь m2m между таблицами shows и genre

И ради всего святого исправьте названия своих переменных.

Comment: films_country -> film's country -> country of film -> страна фильма. Но вижу, что выносит мозг :) А вообще, по рекомендациям полностью с вами согласен! Я все так сейчас сделал, потому как только учусь (пишу для себя) и все названия такие сложные, включая префиксы, чтоб понять и не забыть что за что отвечает. Как доделаю все, приведу в читаемый вид, как вы и говорите.

Comment: По поводу get_or_create. Объясните пожалуйста... Я взял этот пример из документации Джанго - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create , в конце есть про ManyToMany. Как я понимаю, логика должна быть следующая: идет проверка наличия значения (Польша), если значение есть, создаем в "сводной таблице" запись Фильм-Страна, если нету значения, заносим в таблицу Стран "Польшу" и опять же создаем в "сводной таблице" Фильм-Страну с только что созданной "Польшей". Если не прав, прошу объяснить, где именно. Спасибо.

Comment: По поводу таблиц жанра. Я спрашивал на форумах людей, нужно ли поступить так, как вы рекомендуете - все мне ответили, что нет, потому как это "значение", а не сущность. Видимо сколько людей, столько и мнений.

Comment: Попробовал ваш код: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PlaceCountries'

Comment: исправил код, проверил, теперь точно работает.
по поводу жанра - это не мнение, тут без вариантов, читайте про нормальную форму БД. Есть конечно случаи, когда в силу оптимизации мы прибегаем к денормализации, но это точно не ваш случай и вам об этом задумываться рано.
А код - срочно рефакторить, иначе он долго не протянет